# SSL Certificate with https

Tags: ssl, insecure-connection

Hi I have SSL Certificate installed website which is purchased from godaddy. After the installation and activation of ssl certificate , I unable to find that https in my url it is always remains with http..  I Want to fix that issue kindly please tell me how to fix this issue

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what programming language do you use?

Comment: Can't answer from this much information.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on a go daddy forum:

If you want to redirect all the pages on the site to HTTPS, you could select either Match Path, or Root Redirect, depending on where you wish to redirect them. The Root Redirect directs the visitor to the root/index page of the target domain name. Match Path would redirect the visitor to the same content path, such as from http://example.com/page1.html to https://example.com/page1.html.

I’ve included some more information at the link below:

Redirect URLs with Your Hosting Account

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5120

Hope that helps.

Comment: it is possible to have the ssl certificate only for the forms in site in my site i have more than 10 pages but in some 2 or 3 pages having the form . it is possible to have the ssl certificate in form pages only. Thanks in advance

Comment: Having https pages in your entire won't hurt your website, ultimately it will improve users trust and confidence over the website and also a single certificate you just need for entire website, there is no limit of pages.